# How to check and apply CSS to typed words in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a typing test website almost everything is done except the logic part, I mean how can I apply CSS to particular words those are not matching with the given paragraph words.
I converted both the paragraph and textarea values from string to an array and tried comparing their elements with each other and gave the CSS to the wrong words and correct words.
instead of particualr word whole textarea is receiving the css to overcome this I wrote a function which wrap each element of textarea by span, but and assign them different id now how can i target those id to change their style